# Error Converting Bytes to Int (Python 2.7)

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am working in Python 2.7 and am reading in data as bytes (it's a .ecg file), but I need to convert it to integer values.

```
packetID = int(holter.read(1), 2)
packetSS = int(holter.read(2), 2)
packetFB = int(holter.read(2), 2)
```

This returns the error

```
invalid literal for int() with base 2: '\x01'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you're reading binary data, not ASCII numbers, so you need a different way to convert: the [`struct` module](https://docs.python.org/2/library/struct.html).

```
import struct
packetID = struct.unpack('B', holter.read(1))[0]
packetSS = struct.unpack('H', holter.read(2))[0]
```

Alternatively you can read them all at once:

```
packetID, packetSS, packetFB = struct.unpack('BHH', holter.read(5))
```

Comment: What is the significance of B and H?

Comment: @jrs11 those are the format codes for an unsigned byte and an unsigned half-word (2 bytes). If you need signed, use the lower case `'b'` or `'h'`. The full table of codes is in the documentation that I linked.

Comment: My new error is: 'unpack requires a string argument of length 1'

Comment: @jrs11 `read(1)` should return a string of length 1, unless you're at the end of the file.

Comment: @jrs11 I can't help you. Look at what the `read` calls are returning and do the appropriate thing.

Answer (score 0):

`int()` converts a string representation of *digits* such as `'1'` to an integer. If you want to convert a one-character bytestring to an integer, you can use `ord()`. However, if you want to convert more than one byte at a time you can use the `struct` module, specifically `struct.unpack`.